# I have recycleview which contain 4000 data when it load App isn't responding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working in a app
App conatins Alot of data in it more than 4000
Images, name ,phone,Image size is more than 250kb in hd quality
When data is load in a app
App isn't responding  Close and wait dialog box appears
How i can manage it ?
4000 data is in Arraylist

Comment: `4000 data is in Arraylist`. This. Use db and feed your list as needed

Comment: You should load data, chunk by chunk. It's better to use Paging2 Library (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

Comment: Can arraylist give first 50 than when scrool end next 50 and so on

Answer (score 0):

To logically handle the issue of improving the performance of your application, you first need a local database (sqlite,room,realm,active android , ...) where you can manage the data (for better control, of course!)
And to use photos with that quality, if your program can connect to the Internet, read the photo addresses from there and save the photo address along with that text in a line that you can use it easily (because usually In any type of database, they do not store the image directly in the table.

First, they put it in a separate server or repository and only display the address of the saved path in the table.)

In terms of display in Recycler View, it is better that the photos you use have a smaller volume (both in terms of size and size) in addition to their quality, and you can use the same images, but in the size of a thumb strap. The quality of the first view is not important, you can add more details to the items to say that after clicking on this item, now that photo will be displayed in high quality!)

If the number of your records is too much for the show and ... the recycler makes the view itself because it makes the view every time (that is, for example, it brings 10 records in each show), it can handle this issue, but! For better efficiency of your app, it is better to use the infinite paging or scrolling feature.

Comment: is this possible arraylist give first 50 than scroll end next 50 and so on

Comment: This is what you say is usually used for chat pages. This is how it works. Each time the user goes to the bottom of the message page, the method that is given the task of receiving information from the database, based on the type of configuration we gave it, puts the next 10 message IDs in the array and displays them. And it does the same thing every time it scrolls to the bottom.
  I do not know if this is the right way to do it. Because infinite paging and scrolling modes definitely work better than this in the field you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit and offset with your query:

For example:

1. We have a table with 5 records of id column, values are 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 in respective 5 rows.
2. IF perform select * from TABLE_NAME: it returned all records from a table in order 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 .
3. If we need a total(e.g. limit) 1 record and it should start from offset index 2, then use

select * from TABLE_NAME limit 1 offset 2

This will return record index | 3 | as request limit = 1 & offset index = 2.

The same can be achieved using select * from company limit 2, 1;

Note, here 2 is offset & 1 is limit(order reverse).

Since Android SDK does not provide a separate attribute to set offset, in that case last 'limit' attribute of SQLiteDatabase.query(..., limit) can be used as limit 2, 1.